# haproxy not load balancing between 2 servers

Tags: haproxy

I have two ports open on my backend servers, one for https requests and one for websocket requests. The websockets will use http, not https. I would like my haproxy instance to send an http 301 redirect to a client request that will redirect the client directly to a backend server. After the redirect the client should directly communicate with the backend server, regardless of it being a websocket connection or an https connection. Below is my config. It works in the sense that it redirects traffic appropriately, but it only redirects to the first server, never to the second one. Why isnt it using round robin to hit both servers?

```
defaults
    mode http
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 3000ms
    timeout server 3000ms
    timeout tunnel 0

frontend server-frontend
    bind LB_IP:443
    http-request redirect code 301 prefix https
    default_backend server-backend

backend server-backend
    balance roundrobin
    server s1 SERVER1_IP:8443
    server s2 SERVER2_IP:8443

frontend websocket-frontend
    bind LB_IP:80
    http-request redirect code 301 prefix http
    default_backend websocket-backend

backend websocket-backend
    balance roundrobin
    server ws1 SERVER1_IP:8080
    server ws2 SERVER2_IP:8080
```

Comment: Is there some reason that you can't just use `haproxy` which is specifically designed for this purpose?

Comment: I was originally using haproxy but I thought it can't do a round Robin redirect?

Comment: You certainly can. The line `balance roundrobin` can be added to the config to achieve this along with other lines to redirect to wherever you want on the backend servers.

Comment: What I want is for a client to hit haproxy, get back a http 302 redirect to a backend server and then the client can communicate directly with the back end server. Are you saying it can do this? How is that done? I tried round Robin and it seemed like haproxy was always on the middle

Comment: Your question doesn't include any of that. Edit it and provide an explanation of what you want to do and include example such as what you have tried and where it didn't function.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I have updated it

Comment: If you comment out the first backend server and restart the service, does it work? If not, then you'll need to look at the logs of the second server to determine what's going on.

Comment: Thanks again for all your help. There was actually an error in my testing program. I now got it working, but only if i disable ssl in my server. I need to figure out how to get ssl to pass through haproxy and redirect to an actual https server

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.